# stuck in android facebook tutorial

Tags: android, facebook

I am following the android tutorial :http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/

And there is a error occurs on this line:

```
new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
```

The method `getActivity()` is undefined for type MainActivity.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this,
```

instead of

```
new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
```

becuase in example link he is using Fragment .in case of Fragment [getActivity ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) return   *Activity this fragment is currently associated with*